# How to reinitialise a git bare repo so all files are published again?

Tags: git

I'm working on a website, and I'm using git for version control.
I set up a server for testing purposes, created a git bare repo there and pushed the master branch ( `git push staging master`).

I got an error – I had forgotten to set up permissions on the destination folder properly. I fix the permissions, tried pushing again… but git said everything was up to date. Adding the flag -f didn't make any difference. So since it was a fresh push I deleted the bare repo, set it up again, and everything worked.

Eventually, I made a new branch for features I intend to test before merging to the production branch. Then I made some bug fixes on the production branch, so I rebased the test branch in order to keep those bug fixes. And finally I published it with `git push staging new-branch`.

However, it didn't work as intended; some changes present in the new-branch updated base didn't make it to the remote server. I must've done something wrong, so I better just push the whole thing again… oh. Just like before, I don't know how to do that.

So, how can I force git to reupload all files without deleting the bare repo and configuring it again?

I also tried `git push staging new-branch --delete` and repushing it afterwards, but the missing commits were still missing after that.

**EDIT:**

The remote branch I'm pushing to was created with `git init --bare` and its `hooks/post-receive` is configured to:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=/home/<nu_username>/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

**EDIT 2:**

I think I finally started understanding what is, to most, obvious: (ab)using git for publishing is, actually, a two-step process. First the changes are pushed, and then the repo is checked out. I had always thought of this as a single action, not understanding what was happening in reality.

So, in both of the situations I described, the changes were successfully pushed. The issue was always with the checkout.

In situation 1, the repo's permissions were set properly, so the changes were pushed correctly. Since the repo was up-to-date, further push attempts wouldn't trigger the post-receive hook.

In situation 2, `new-branch`'s changes were pushed correctly, but the branch actually being checked out was `master`. Furthermore, I hadn't pushed `master`'s latest commits.

In both cases, checking out the remote repo's correct branch would publish the changes I wanted it to publish in the first place.

This was all, therefore, caused by a massive misunderstanding of what was actually happening between my writing `git push` and the files showing up on the server.

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to `commit` before running `push`. Are there unstaged files? If not, does your feature branch commit show up in the Git history?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I can confirm the changes I'm mentioning have been committed. It's something like: master was on commit A, I created new-branch from it, might've committed something (B) then did a few commits on master (C). I rebased new-branch to C, and in the meantime added some commits to both master (D) and new-branch (E). The changes I've noticed not being pushed were committed on C.

Comment: It would help if you provided full steps to reproduce what you did, i.e. a [mcve]. With permissions, also make sure you document which user each step is executed as. Also, pay attention to the permissions, sticky-bits and ACLs of parent directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting with several misconceptions, and with what I think is a bad overall plan (though lots of people use it successfully).

In particular:

- Git doesn't *publish* things.  Git makes, stores, and manipulates commits, through a database of Git *objects*.  The commits store files, in the unit of a whole commit: you either have a commit (which has a snapshot of all of its files), or you don't have the commit.
- Git never pushes *files*.  Git pushes *commits*.

Both of these mean, at least to me, that Git is a very *bad* deployment tool.  People do use it as one, but to do so, you must twist it around somewhat.  You haven't described how you've twisted it around, which is one issue here.

The two common ways to twist Git into a deployment system are:

- set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead` with a non-bare repository, or
- use a post-receive hook to do a `git --work-tree=<path> checkout -f` with a bare repository.

You did mention "bare repository" in both the title and the body, so perhaps you set up a post-receive hook like this.  If so:

1. Make sure your post-receive hook really works.  (This is somewhat difficult to test, but one method is to have it log something to a `/tmp` file every time it runs, so that you can observe it running.)
2. Remember that you're now (ab?)using Git's *index* to index / cache the `--work-tree` path.  There is only one index, so this only works with one work-tree.
3. Remember that `git checkout -f` checks out the *current branch*.  It only really makes sense to do this if the `git push` actually updated that particular branch name (but generally should be mostly harmless in other cases).  A bare repository has a current branch, just like any repository.  It also has an index, which is a little odd but is just like any repository.  The index indexes and caches the work-tree.  A bare repository doesn't have a work-tree, which is why it is odd for it to have an index ... but in the `git checkout`, you temporarily set it up (for the duration of that one `git checkout` command) with a work-tree.  So that's the work-tree that this index is indexing/caching.  Any later `git checkout` had better use the same path, otherwise the index will be indexing the wrong work-tree.

   In a bare repository, the current branch generally starts out being `master` and generally *stays* `master`.  So the commit you'll check out is the tip commit of `master`.  Adding new branch names and/or changing which commit(s) the other branch names identify has no effect as long as the name `master` still identifies the same commit.
4. If you're using some other command—or `git checkout -f` with other arguments—put that in your question; we need to see that, before we can actually help.

If the index is out of sync with the actual work-tree—which can happen if other things, such as your web server itself, manipulate files *in* the work-tree—the `git checkout` may not function quite the way you'd like.  I personally think the right approach is to *not* attempt to use Git as a deployment system, but I don't have any recommendations about what *to* use either.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I've updated the question to show that / how I set up a post-receive hook. I don't yet fully grasp how git works, even though I've been (ab)using it for publishing in the most basic ways (single branch, only commit and push) for a couple of years. Could this be an issue with the index, then? Or is pushing a different branch something that shouldn't be done on bare repositories? My apologies in advance, I'm sure I still have plenty of misconceptions…

Comment: OK: so your `git checkout -f` is going to create-or-use the index (the first one ever has to create it as it doesn't exist until the first checkout or other index-using operation). That will *fill in* the index from the commit named by the current branch, probably `master`. Later, after you `git push` to the repository, Git will run your post-receive hook. That will use the index, which is indexing (caching) this `/var/www/html` directory, and compares the currently-checked-out commit there, from the commit that `master` named before, to what `master` names now.

Comment: If `master` now names a *different* commit, the index, and therefore the work-tree, will need some updating. Git will use the index to figure out a minimal update, taking into account Git's own assumptions about what's in the work-tree based on the index-as-cache. If you've created a new branch `staging`, so that `master` still names the *same* commit, Git sees that you're going from commit X to commit X which requires no changes at all, and makes no changes in the index or work-tree at all.

Comment: I think I finally understood what happens when pushing changes, and therefore what happened in the cases I mentioned, thanks to your help. I've updated my question with my (possibly / probably flawed) interpretation of what happened.

Comment: Yes, thinking of it as two separate steps helps, because it really is two separate steps. The `push` action sends any required commits and other objects to the receiving Git, then the Git doing the `push` asks or tells the receiving Git to update some set of names (branch names, tag names, other names—all of these are specific forms of *refs*  or references) to some hash ID(s). For each branch name the sender asks or commands to be set, the hash ID the sender provides must be that of a commit in the receiver, hence the first part of send-some-commits.

Comment: The receiver passes the names to the pre-receive and update hooks (if present) and those get veto power: *yes, you may set name X* and *no, you may not set name Y* for instance. The receiving Git then either rejects the entire push, or accepts part or all of it; it's now done and the sender can safely disconnect. Last, the receiver invokes the post-receive hook, passing to that hook the set of names that were actually changed. The post-receive hook can do anything at all as it's just any executable, but it needs to use a little care as it is running in a hook enviornment.